# How are token vectors calculated in spacy-pytorch-transformers

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch, spacy, spacy-transformers

I am currently working with the [`spacy-pytorch-transformer`](https://github.com/explosion/spacy-pytorch-transformers) package to experiment with the respective embeddings.
When reading the introductionary article (essentially the GitHub README), my understanding was that the token-level embeddings are the mean over the embeddings of all corresponding word pieces, i.e. `embed(complex)` would be the same as `1/2 * embed(comp#) * embed(#lex)`.

According to the BERT paper, this should simply utilize the `last_hidden_state` property of the network, but my MCVE below shows that this is not the same for Spacy 2.1.8 and spacy-pytorch-transformers 0.4.0, for at least BERT and RoBERTa (have not verified it for more models):

```
import spacy
import numpy as np
nlp = spacy.load("en_pytt_robertabase_lg")  # either this or the BERT model
test = "This is a test"  # Note that all tokens are directly aligned, so no mean has to be calculated.
doc = nlp(test)
# doc[0].vector and doc.tensor[0] are equal, so the results are equivalent.
print(np.allclose(doc[0].vector, doc._.pytt_last_hidden_state[1, :]))
# returns False
```

The offset of 1 for the hidden states is due to the `<CLS>` token as the first input, which corresponds to the sentence classification task; I even checked with any available other token for my sentence (which has no token alignment problems according to `doc._.pytt_alignment`), so there is no way I missed something here.

[According to the source code](https://github.com/explosion/spacy-pytorch-transformers/blob/master/spacy_pytorch_transformers/pipeline/tok2vec.py), the corresponding hook overwrites simply to return the corresponding row in the tensor, so I do not see any transformation here. Is there something obvious that I am missing here, or is this deviating from the expected behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is a more elaborate weighting scheme behind this, which also accounts for the `[CLS]` and `[SEP]` token outputs in each sequence.

This has also been confirmed by an [issue post from the spaCy developers](https://github.com/explosion/spacy-transformers/issues/68).

Unfortunately, it seems that this part of the code has since moved with the renaming to `spacy-transformers`.